# Zend Router Regex not routing as expected

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, url-routing

Zend Bootstrap is not following this route:

```
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex (
        '(.+)-hospital-lottery',
        array('module' => 'default','controller'=>'hospital','action'=>'index'),
        array(1 => 'province')
    );
```

Trial URL being http://mydomain.com/something-hospital-lottery

No luck even including a fourth sprintf param...I feel this has something to do with a lack of /'s.

Comment: Because it's not being added properly? (-;

Comment: I'm adding it with:
$router->addRoute('hospitals', $route);
where I have:
     $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router = $frontController->getRouter();
I already have several other routes in the file, it's just this one that I had to change to use regex...

Comment: Solved. Issue was that another route in the routine was overriding:

(.+)-hospital-lottery

/:province

The latter was capturing whatever-hospital-lottery as the province param.

A lesson to me and whomever else with this problem to mind and respect the order of your route declarations...!

Will post accepted answer in 5 hours when I'm able.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine, I tested it and it worked fine.

How are you attempting to add it to the router?

Try adding this line after you create the route:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->addRoute('h-lottery', $route);
```

Comment: See my comment above...I'm adding it just like my other routes that work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex (
    '(.*)-hospital-lottery',
    array('module' => 'default','controller'=>'hospital','action'=>'index'),
    array(1 => 'province')
);
```

Comment: Where it goes actually? when you visit your trial URL?

Comment: It skips down to my catch-all route at the bottom of the route listing, and tries to send it to a controller called something-hospital-lottery. So just basically just doesn't detect my route above as a matching condition